# Pages 5.2: How to insert date field in other language than system default?

Tags: macos, pages

My system language is American English. When I insert a date field in Pages (5.2) it follows this format, even though I've set the spelling and grammar language to Dutch. Is it possible to insert a date field in Dutch?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your region is set to dutch in system-preferences, the language can be set to american but the region setting takes care of the date-format
like in this picture:
[image]

Comment: That seems to set the default languages of all my programs to Dutch, which is not what I want.

Comment: are your settings exactly the same as my screenshot? If i set my system language to american or english al my programs switch to english as they should, you only need to change the settings on the right side.

Comment: what programs switch to dutch?

Comment: Thanks, I did changed the preferred instead of the region language... However, even if I copy you settings, "Insert > Date & Time" gives me the date in English in Pages.

Comment: You mean like this: Sunday, january 5, 2014 at 7:08:09 AM? Or like this: Sunday 5 january 2014 07:08:09? If it is the first option I'd like to know what version of pages you are using since it is not supposed to do that, if it is the second option then it is just working as intended because the region setting does not change the language of the date only the format

Comment: I think you've just answered my question. I would have expected that Pages was able to insert "zondag 5 januari 2014" instead of "Sunday, january 5, 2014", but apperently this is not possible...

Answer (score 0):

Just go to advanced, and change the date format there. Then introduce your automatic date in Pages (or any other automatic field). Finally, go back to your original date format if you wish.